# Azure Identity gives 401 error using CSOM in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-identity

I have a .NET Core 6 Azure webjob for creating new MS Teams and SharePoint Online sites. When executing, it first creates a log entry in a SharePoint list so we can track the status of the request. I'm authenticating with the Azure Identity package (DefaultAzureCredential):

```
public async Task<ClientContext> GetClientContext(string siteUrl, ILogger logger = null)
{
    logger?.LogInformation($"Trying to fetch a new token to build context for {siteUrl}");

    var _tenantUrl = new Uri(siteUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

    // Setup a listener to monitor logged events.
    using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();

    var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(
        new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
        {
            ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
            ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
            ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
            ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
            ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
            ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
            ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
            ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = false,
            Diagnostics =
                {
                    IsLoggingEnabled = true,
                    IsLoggingContentEnabled = true,

                }
        }
        );
    var _accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
        new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { $"{_tenantUrl}/.default" }) { }
    );

    var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager();

    var _clientContext = authenticationManager.GetAccessTokenContext(siteUrl, _accessToken.Token);

    return _clientContext;
}
```

For testing purposes, I'm using Interactive browser login. I'm logging in with my admin account who has an active SharePoint admin role (which has been activated through PIM). I've also added extra logging to try to figure out what is going on, but it seems a token is being fetched correctly:

```
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] Checking client info returned from the server..
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] Saving token response to cache..
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] [Region discovery] Not using a regional authority.
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving AT in cache and removing overlapping ATs...
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] Looking for scopes for the authority in the cache which intersect with https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/.default
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] Intersecting scope entries count - 1
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] Matching entries after filtering by user - 1
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving Id Token and Account in cache ...
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving RT in cache...
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] IsLegacyAdalCacheEnabled: yes
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] Not writing FRT in ADAL legacy cache.
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898]
       
       === Token Acquisition finished successfully:
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898]  AT expiration time: 20/09/2023 16:35:07 +00:00, scopes: https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/user_impersonation https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/.default. source: IdentityProvider
[Informational] Azure-Identity: False MSAL 4.54.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.22 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621 [2023-09-20 15:12:01Z - 7bfc4350-99cb-47b7-8d68-611880beb898] Fetched access token from host login.microsoftonline.com.
[Informational] Azure-Identity: InteractiveBrowserCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/.default ] ParentRequestId:  ExpiresOn: 2023-09-20T16:35:07.2740536+00:00
[Informational] Azure-Identity: DefaultAzureCredential credential selected: Azure.Identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential
[Informational] Azure-Identity: DefaultAzureCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/.default ] ParentRequestId:  ExpiresOn: 2023-09-20T16:35:07.2740536+00:00
```

What I'm not understanding is that I receive an error as soon as I'm executing a CSOM query, for example:

```
private void UpdateListItem()
{
    if (ListItem != null)
    {
        //... setting field values

        ListItem.Update();
        Context.ExecuteQuery(); // <-- 401 error
    }
}
```

I've tested manually adding a new item to the logging list (in the browser) with the same admin account and that seems to work without issues.

When the project is deployed, it uses a Managed Identity with the necessary API permissions to authenticate, that also works without issues.

Why am I struggling with a 401 Unauthorized error here? Any ideas?